# how to customize x-axis in a plot for R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, graph

I would like to customize my own x-axis using plot in R. What i want is that the x-axis would display 40-52, then from 1-40 again, something in the attachment shown below. My data is from 2015 week 40 to 2018 week 4, and I have tried something like 2017_40 to 2018_4, but this will make the graph look really cramped.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `xaxt='n'` in your plot to suppress printing the x-axis,  then use `axis` to print whatever you want.

```
x = 40:92
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y, ylim=c(-2,2), type='l', xaxt='n')

xlab = ifelse(x>52, x-52,x)
axis(side=1, at=40:92, labels=xlab)
```

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for answering, but it won't work if the data is labeled as 1-52, there isn't anything above 52

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. You are creating the labels.  Do you mean that the actual x-values that you are plotting are 1-52  but you want the labels 40,...,52,1, ...39?

Comment: nvm, because the data given to me is 40-52, then 1-39, so i just  need to change 1-39 to 53-91, and everything works fine. THANK YOU!